# How to add custom font into Google Webdesigner?

Tags: fonts, google-web-designer

How do you add a custom font into `Google Webdesigner`?

I see there is an option to include `Google Fonts`, but I can't find a way to include one of own personal ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Code View` add `@font-face` CSS as you would in a normal html document. Put the font files in `assets` folder.

Example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: LouisRegular;
  src: url(assets/LouisRegular.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: LouisItalic;
  src: url(assets/LouisItalic.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: LouisBoldItalic;
  src: url(assets/LouisBoldItalic.ttf);
}
```

Now simply select the div and apply the `font-family` from top or from CSS panel in RHS. Note top bar might not give you any auto suggestion of the new font but add it any ways and it should work.

Note: Fonts are often more than 200kb which can hurt your banner budget, if that is the case I will recommend using text as images instead of font.

Comment: I also realised that you can't really do anything short of adding your own CSS. Since most people are probably using `Google Web Designer` as a tool to create ads, it's worth mentioning that most "ad formats" do not let you include your own font face. GDN currently supports custom fonts via `Google Fonts` though. Creating SVG outlines of the texts it the fallback I had to use personally. Make sure to check the specs guys.

Comment: I am using GWD to create some ads with double click as publisher & thanks for the warring, I will see if they support custom font.

Comment: Is there an issue with licensing for paid fonts?